# Using Simple imputer replace NaN values with mean error

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace 2 missing NaN values in data using the SimpleImputer.
I load my data as follow;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('country-income.csv', header=None)
df.head(20)
```

[image]

As we can see I have 2 NaN values which I am trying to replace with mean() values using SimpleImputer and I get the following error:

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', fill_value=None)
imputer.fit(df)
```

[image]

Because I have some categorical data (hence the error), I tried to take only the numeric columns so I tried this method:

```
missing_vars_numeric = [var for var in df.columns
                          if df[var].isnull().mean() > 0 and df[var].dtype != "0"]
missing_vars_numeric


Output: [1,2]
```

But when I use `missing_vars_numeric in the imputer I get the following error:

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', fill_value=None)
imputer.fit(missing_vars_numeric)

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1. 2.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

[image]

I also tried using astype() and It did not work for me. What am I missing?

Sample of the DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': ['Region', 'India','Brazil', 'USA','Brazil','USA','India','Brazil','India','USA','India'],
                   '1': ['Age', '49', '32', '35','43','45','40','NaN','53','55','42'],
                   '2': ['Income', 86400, 57600, 64800,73200,'NaN',69600,62400,94800,99600,80400],
                   '3': ['Online Shopper','No','Yes',' No',' No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes']},
                  index=['0', '1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### One-liner

```
df.fillna(df.select_dtypes(np.number).mean(), inplace=True)
```

- `df.select_dtypes(np.number)` selects only the numeric columns of the dataframe
- `.mean()` computes the mean of each column, returning a new dataframe
- `df.fillna()` accepts a dataframe (or other forms) to impute NaNs in named columns
- `inplace` just means it happens in the original dataframe itself, without making a copy

You can probably use this to accomplish many more variations of imputation - replacing `.mean()` with whatever you need.

---

## Update with `df` from OP

The example dataframe you provided has columns with mixtures of data types. Every column contains strings (e.g. `'49'` is a string). Only column `2` contains integer types.

When a pandas column contains strings, the column's dtype becomes `object`. This type is not part of `np.number`, meaning you cannot select any columns with the method in my `one-liner` solution above.

*Note: OP originally showed a CSV being loaded, which pandas likely loaded into the correct data types. The example snippet for `df = pd.DataFrame(...)` gives nearly all values as strings. There is a difference then between the original question and the updated snippet.*

### Solution

I will walk you through the steps required based on your example snippet.

In general, you need to ensure that all your column types are correct. E.g. the `Age` column should have type `int`, whereas `Region` is `str`. You need to convert your column types.

```py
In [1]: import pandas as pd, numpy as np
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'0': ['Region', 'India','Brazil', 'USA','Brazil','USA','India','Brazil','India','USA','India'],
   ...:                    '1': ['Age', '49', '32', '35','43','45','40','NaN','53','55','42'],
   ...:                    '2': ['Income', 86400, 57600, 64800,73200,'NaN',69600,62400,94800,99600,80400],
   ...:                    '3': ['Online Shopper','No','Yes',' No',' No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes']},
   ...:                   index=['0', '1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'])
   ...:
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
         0    1       2               3
0   Region  Age  Income  Online Shopper
1    India   49   86400              No
2   Brazil   32   57600             Yes
3      USA   35   64800              No
4   Brazil   43   73200              No
5      USA   45     NaN             Yes
6    India   40   69600             Yes
7   Brazil  NaN   62400              No
8    India   53   94800             Yes
9      USA   55   99600              No
10   India   42   80400             Yes

In [4]: df.dtypes
Out[4]:
0    object
1    object
2    object
3    object
dtype: object
```

Column names stored as the first row, so make them actual column names and remove that first row:

```py
In [5]: column_names = df.iloc[0].tolist()
In [6]: df = df.iloc[1:]
In [7]: df.columns = column_names
```

The missing NaN values are stored as string: replace with `numpy.nan`:

```py
In [8]: df[df == "NaN"] = np.nan
```

Convert the types of all columns, using a column names to type mapping - not all `object`. Note that np.nan is actually a `float` - so we can't use `int`:

```py
In [9]: df = df.astype({"Region": str, "Age": float, "Income": float, "Online Shopper": bool})
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
    Region   Age   Income  Online Shopper
1    India  49.0  86400.0            True
2   Brazil  32.0  57600.0            True
3      USA  35.0  64800.0            True
4   Brazil  43.0  73200.0            True
5      USA  45.0      NaN            True
6    India  40.0  69600.0            True
7   Brazil   NaN  62400.0            True
8    India  53.0  94800.0            True
9      USA  55.0  99600.0            True
10   India  42.0  80400.0            True

In [11]: df.dtypes
Out[11]:
Region             object
Age               float64
Income            float64
Online Shopper       bool
dtype: object
```

The one-liner solution now works:

```py
In [12]: imputed_df = df.fillna(df.select_dtypes(np.number).mean())
In [13]: imputed_df
Out[13]:
    Region        Age        Income  Online Shopper
1    India  49.000000  86400.000000            True
2   Brazil  32.000000  57600.000000            True
3      USA  35.000000  64800.000000            True
4   Brazil  43.000000  73200.000000            True
5      USA  45.000000  76533.333333            True
6    India  40.000000  69600.000000            True
7   Brazil  43.777778  62400.000000            True
8    India  53.000000  94800.000000            True
9      USA  55.000000  99600.000000            True
10   India  42.000000  80400.000000            True
```

You might want to convert the columns to new types, e.g. making `Age` of type `int`. I will leave this is an exercise for you. I think this shows you many of the tools you will need to work it out.

Comment: You could continue to use `SimpleImputer` using your original code, but simple pass it the numerical columns: `df.select_dtypes(np.number)`. You will then need to  insert those back into your original dataframe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried this df.fillna(df.select_dtypes(np.number).mean(), inplace=True) but it did not help and I still get NaN values

Comment: If you can update your post to give a sample of your dataframe (in a format that can be copy-pasted), perhaps I can tweak my answer to work for your use case.

Comment: thank you I added the sample in my original post, thank you for your help

Comment: @royalTiger - please see my update with the steps to solve your case.

Comment: n1k31t4 this is the best explanation I have seen, it is all clear now , thank you very much, very helpful

Comment: @royalTiger - you're welcome! If your question is answered, please accept the answer